# # in Get Request Django

Tags: django, get

```
def c_bookmarklet_submit(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    title = request.GET['title']
    url = request.GET['url']
    description = request.GET['description']
    site_name = request.GET['site_name']
    pic = request.GET['pic']
```

Above is my get request in my view.py in Django. It works well, however there are some URLs and titles that contain a "#" and that completely messes up the get request. Any idea how to get around that from the views side of the things?

Comment: What error do you see ?

Comment: "Key 'url' not found in <QueryDict: {u'title': [u'Next For ']}>", almost as if after the # in the url, which has the format ?title=title#&ulr=...,  nothing is being read.

Comment: not a form, actually a bookmarklet, which takes the information from the current page and puts it in a url and redirects to this page. So i do not have too much control over the input. And correct, whenever I have a # anywhere I get an error, but this specific error is bc a # is present in the url

Comment: What url are you passing through?... (you also have it spelt `ulr` above)

Comment: http://hughesj15.pythonanywhere.com/bookmarklet-submit/?title=Next%20For%20#BlackLivesMatter: Google Backs A Social Network To Keep Police Accountable&url=http://www.wired.com/2015/11/blacklivesmatter-tech-google/&description=Backed by Google, #BlackLivesMatter founder Patrisse Cullors is building a social network for victims of racial injustice...&pic=http://www.wired.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/GettyImages-483700330-1200x630-e1447811346923.jpg&site_name=WIRED

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you can do from the view side; anything after # is simply not sent from the browser to the server. You need to encode it before sending, presumably in your bookmarklet.